# Смена ссылки каждый день

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```
<a href="" title="ТЕКСТ"><div class="article9">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="текст">
        <for>Какой-то текст</for>               
</div></a>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы менялась только ссылка, а `img`, `for`, `title` оставались как были. При чем менялись в зависимости от дня. Как узнать какой день на компьютере пользователя я знаю:

```
function setNewYearBg() {
  var now = new Date(),
      month = now.getMonth(),
      day = now.getDate(),
  if( (month == 11 && day >= 25) || (month == 11 && day <= 28 ) ) {    

  }
  else if( (month == 11 && day == 29 ) ) {    
        document.body.classList.add('newyear_sunset');
  }
}

setNewYearBg();
```

Вопрос как менять ссылку. Сейчас у меня в CSS прописан код, относящийся к классу дива:

```
.article9 { 
    url(www.google.ru);
    ...
}

.article9:hover {   
    url(www.google.ru);
    ...
}

.article9 for {
    ...
}

.article9:hover for {   
    ...        
}

.article9>img {
    ...
}
```

Я попробовал в `css` прописать `url`, чтобы затем менять этот параметр в условиях (`if`) времени. Но ссылка не работает. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: а зачем вам делать это классом ?

Comment: а какие есть предложения?

Comment: Менять атрибут href ссылки

Comment: Так как раз-таки и вопрос в том как поменять атрибут href ссылки..

Comment: в ответе это есть :)

Comment: Но как видите там проблема - не работает почему-то ;)

Comment: вижу что работает и делает ровно то, что вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что если у пользователя сбит часовой пояс или что еще хуже нет батарейки? Раз вы делаете ссылки, то и делайте на стороне сервера расчет времени и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Для текущей разметки:

1. **javascript**

   ```js
   document.getElementsByClassName("article9")[0].parentElement.setAttribute("href", "link");
   ```

   ```html
   <a href="" title="ТЕКСТ">
     <div class="article9">
       <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="текст">
         <for>Какой-то текст</for>               
     </div>
   </a>
   ```
2. **jQuery**

```js
$(".article9").parent().attr("href", "ссылка");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" title="ТЕКСТ">
  <div class="article9">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="текст">
      <for>Какой-то текст</for>               
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Использовал вариант с JS, но не работает. Т.е. я в if добавил: "document.getElementsByClassName("article9")[0].parentElement.setAttribute("href", "www.google.ru");" 

Но при нажатии по ссылке - она не работает.

Comment: @user250973 атрибут href заполнился необходимой ссылкой?

Comment: Где именно? В JS вы видите. А в html я оставил это поле пустым..

Comment: @user250973 после выполнения функции проинспектируйте элемент на предмет заполнения атрибута.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что Вы имеете ввиду. По идеи, JS-код должен был уже установить атрибут в "article9"..

Comment: @user250973 в `article9` атрибут точно не должен был добавляться. Я к чему все это веду - пытаюсь узнать подробности возникновения ошибки. Есть предположения, что либо у Вас не один DOM элемент имеет класс `article9` или у Вас JS-код не отрабатывает корректно. Поэтому и прошу Вас после выполнения JS-кода проинспектировать разметку страницы на предмет заполнения атрибута `href` у родительского элемента `<a>` контейнера с классом `article9`.

Comment: Нет, у меня лишь один класс называется "article9"

Comment: @user250973 можете показать весь ваш код? Например добавить его на https://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rwv9k2ca/

Comment: @user250973 у Вас ошибка в строчке `day = now.getDate()`. Там вместо `,` должна быть `;`.

Comment: Да, я когда Вам прислал это увидел и исправил сразу же - без изменений.

Comment: @user250973 а если так? https://jsfiddle.net/9o736812/

Comment: нет, без изменений.. в принципе, мне нужно, чтобы ссылка вела на мой же сайт, возможно, это как-то поможет.. т.е. открыть html файл на сервере..